# Getting ConcurrentModificationException despite using synchronized to sort a Collection

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to sort the collection using threaded methods where the methods call comparator classes individually

```
public class ThreadedSort{
   public ThreadedSort(){
       ThreadedIDSort idSort=new ThreadedIDSort();
       ThreadedNameSort nameSort=new ThreadedNameSort();
       ThreadedSalarySort salarySort=new ThreadedSalarySort();

        ExecutorService threadExecutor=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        threadExecutor.execute(idSort);
        threadExecutor.execute(nameSort);
        threadExecutor.execute(salarySort);

   }
}
```

Each threaded method looks like this:

```
public class ThreadedIDSort implements Runnable, EmployeeInterface {
    public synchronized void run(){
        employeeList.sort(new IDComparator());
    }
  }
```

The ID Compartator class is as follows:

```
public class IDComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
        return a.getID()-b.getID();
    }

}
```

The employeeList is a list of objects having attributes name, id,  salary and post:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList=new ArrayList<>();
```

Though I added synchronized before run method, editing the list still gives ConcurrentModificationException

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1723)
    at Client.Sort.Threaded.ThreadedNameSort.run(ThreadedNameSort.java:9)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I am trying to sort using name, post and ID all at once using threads.

Comment: Can you include the code for the IDComparator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob Spoor explained why `ConcurrentModificationException` isn't necessarily about threading. But also, you should know this:

The `synchronized` keyword on the `run()` method in your example has no effect.

When you write a synchronized method,

```java
    public synchronized void bar() {
        ...
    }
```

That's the same as if you wrote,

```java
    public void bar() {
        synchronized(this) {
             ...
        }
    }
```

In your example, each of the three tasks that you submit to the executor service is a different `Runnable` object. The keyword, `this`, refers to a different object in each of the three `run()` methods.  Three different threads synchronizing on three different objects is the same as no synchronization at all.

Synchronization is only meaningful when the threads synchronize on the *same* object. The rule is, no two threads will ever be allowed to synchronize on the *same object* at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A `ConcurrentModification` can also occur in single threaded applications. They occur when a collection is both modified and iterated over. That can be as simple as the following:

```
for (String s : myStringList) {
    if ("X".equals(s)) {
        myStringList.remove(s);
    }
}
```

Note that the so-called concurrent collections, from `java.util.concurrent`, have been designed to support this, but most (all?) from `java.util` have the same issue, even if you apply synchronisation.

Without seeing what `employeeList` is exactly, and what `IDComparator` does, it's difficult to say why the exception is thrown in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with same 'employeeList' being modified by concurrently running different threads.

One of the options is to clone the employeeList and assign separate list for sorting.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList=new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Employee>  employeeListByName = employeeList.clone();

ArrayList<Employee>  employeeListBySalary = employeeList.clone();

// use copy of list in respective thread

ThreadedIDSort  -> use employeeList
ThreadedNameSort -> use employeeListByName
ThreadedSalarySort -> use employeeListBySalary
```